# continuous of a function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $U$ be a non-empty open set in $R^2$ and let $f:U\to R$ be a function. Suppose that the first partial derivactives of $f,f_1,f_2$ are defined and bouned on all of $U$. Show that $f$ is continuous on $U$

Comment: do you know how to prove if $U$ were compact?

Comment: what form of the continuous' definition are you allow to use?

Comment: I think it would be for an open set $U$ in $R$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open

Comment: let $p$ be a point $\in f^{-1}W$. Did you try to use: "if $x_n\to p$ then $f(x_n)\to fp$" ? $W$ a relatively open set in $fU$.

Comment: sorry, I still cannot figure it out, could you please give me more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $q$ be a point in $U$.

We'll prove that $f\in C^0(q)$, by showing that if there is a sequence $q_n$ in $U$ that converges to $q$ then the sequence $f(q_n)$ converges to $f(q)$. This is an equivalent formulation  to the $\mathbf{\varepsilon\!-\!\delta}$ 's definition  of ${\Bbb{R}}^2$-continuity.

**Solution**

Let $q_n=(x_n,y_n)$ a sequence in $U$ such that  to $q_n\to q$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be.

From the *mean valued theorem*, for $f$ we can assemble:
$$f(x,b)-f(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{(\xi_1,b)}(x-a),$$
and 
$$f(a,y)-f(a,b)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(a,\xi_2)}(y-b),$$
for some $|\xi_1-a|\le|\xi-a|$ and $|\xi_2-b|\le|y-b|$.

Then
$$f(x_n,y_n)-f(a,b)=f(x_n,y_n)-f(x_n,b)+f(x_n,b)-f(a,b)
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}|_{\xi_1,b)}(x_n-a)
+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{x_n,\xi_2)}(y_n-b)
$$

then

$$|f(x_n,y_n)-f(a,b)|\le M_1|x_n-a|+M_2|y_n-b|$$

We can choose large enough $K$ such that $\forall n\ge K$
we have:
$$|x_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M_1}\quad\mbox{and}\quad |y_n-b|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2M_2},$$
for some bounds $M_1,M_2$ of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ respectively.

So
$$|f(x_n,y_n)-f(a,b)|<\varepsilon,$$
i.e. $f(q_n)$ converges $f(q)$.

Comment: Then use **mean valued thm** [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem ] to estimate $f(x,y)-f(q)$.

Comment: How can we be sure that there will be a sequence converge to $q$ in $U$?

Comment: that is std: take a sequence of disks $D_{1/n}(q)$ then choose any $q_n$ in that disk, for $n\in{\Bbb{N}}$. Then $q_n\to q$